# how to get all speakers' name using actionscript

Tags: actionscript

i don't know how actionscript get all speakers' name, how actionscript can do this？

i know actionscript can get microphone name list by using Microsoft.names

but how to do for speakers ?

like the skype, it can specify which speaker to ring, but how actionscript to implement the same function

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the left and right speakers? If that's the case, use the `SoundTransform` class and the `pan` property:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundTransform.html

Using a value of `-1.0` will mean that your sound will play out of the left speaker, while a value of `1.0` will mean that your sound will play from the right speaker. This is what Skype is doing from what I can tell.

```
// create our sound and play it, storing the SoundChannel created
var sound:Sound             = new Sound( new URLRequest( "../assets/myMusic.mp3" ) );
var channel:SoundChannel    = sound.play( 0, 10 ); // loops 10 times

// create our SoundTransform object
var st:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform( 1.0, 0.0 );

// add a stage listener for mouse click - we'll take the x position of the click
// and use it to set the pan
this.stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, function( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    // sets the pan between -1.0 and 1.0 depending on where on the stage
    // important - we need to set the soundTransform property on the 
    // SoundChannel for our change to take effect
    st.pan                  = -1.0 + ( e.stageX / stage.stageWidth ) * 2.0;
    channel.soundTransform  = st;
    trace( "Set the pan to " + st.pan );
});
```

Comment: I think he means getting the names such as `Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)` and `Digital Audio (S/PDIF)(High Definition Audio Device)` etc etc.

Comment: yes, xLite is right, what i mean is how actionscript to get the name list for each speaker like skype.for example skype can detect my pc has 2 speakers, one is [Realtek HD Audio Output] and the other is [DroidCam Audio], but how actionscript to do the this?

Comment: hm, i'm not entirely sure that you can - the closest i could find in the docs is the `AudioDecoder` class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/AudioDecoder.html and from what I understand, it's only really useful for AIR on tv devices

Comment: thx, now i use java applet to implement this, that is js call java applet and as call js, by applet to get the name list of all speakers